# How do I change the size of a React DnD Preview Image?

Tags: reactjs, dom, react-hooks, drag-and-drop, react-dnd

I am making a chess game, and I am using React Drag n Drop for the piece movement. I have a problem where the drag image is not scaling with the window size. The image stays at a static 60x60px (the same as the image I am serving from my static folder to the client).

Here is a gif of the problem so you can see:
[Drag image not scaling with original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwAnq.gif)

Here is a code snippet of the "Piece" component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

// React DnD Imports 
import { useDrag, DragPreviewImage, DragLayer } from "react-dnd";

function Piece({ piece }) {
    const { imageFile } = piece;

    // drag and drop configuration
    const [{ isDragging }, drag, preview] = useDrag({
        item: { type: "piece", piece: piece },
        collect: (monitor) => {
            return { isDragging: !!monitor.isDragging() };
        },
    });

    const opacityStyle = {
        opacity: isDragging ? 0.5 : 1,
    };

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <DragPreviewImage connect={preview} src={imageFile} />
            <img style={{ ...opacityStyle }} ref={drag} src={imageFile}></img>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

I've tried the following, but it doesn't work exactly right:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        const img = new Image();
        img.src = imageFile;
        const ctx = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("2d");
        ctx.canvas.width = "100%";
        ctx.canvas.height = "100%";

        img.onload = () => {
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
            img.src = ctx.canvas.toDataURL();
            preview(img);
        };
    }, []);
```

1. Drag Image is transparent
2. If you start dragging between UseEffect calls, you start dragging the whole tile behind the image

I really would love a way to easily tell my DragPreviewImage to scale with the original image... Thank you!

EDIT:
I have discovered the previewOptions property! I got my preview image to center on drag by doing this, but I can't get it to increase in size. Code below:

```
function Piece({ piece }) {
    const { imageFile } = piece;

    const previewOptions = {
        offsetX: 27,
        offsetY: 28,
    };

    // drag and drop configuration
    const [{ isDragging }, drag, preview] = useDrag({
        item: { type: "piece", piece: piece },
        previewOptions,
        collect: (monitor) => {
            return { isDragging: !!monitor.isDragging() };
        },
    });

    const img = new Image();
    img.src = imageFile;
    preview(img, previewOptions);

    const callbackRef = useCallback(
        (node) => {
            drag(node);
            preview(node, previewOptions);
        },
        [drag, preview],
    );

    const opacityStyle = {
        opacity: isDragging ? 0.5 : 1,
    };

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <DragPreviewImage connect={preview} src={imageFile} />
            <img style={{ ...opacityStyle }} ref={drag} src={imageFile} />
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

Comment: If you don't change the opacity and keep it `1`, does it still shrink in size?

Comment: Yes, it still shrinks without the opacity styling.